# How can I create this NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a code to create an NSArray but it doesn't really do what I want.

**This is the code:**

```
NSString *workTime0 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"6:00 - 16:00"];
NSArray *theBreaksArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12:00 - 12:30", nil];

NSMutableArray *nameDictionary = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
                [nameDictionary addObject:workTime0];
                [nameDictionary addObject:theBreaksArray];
```

**This gives me this:**

```
(
   "6:00 - 16:00",
   (
      "12:00 - 12:30"
   )
)
```

**But I want this:**

```
Calendar = 
(
   "6:00 - 16:00",
   (
      "12:00 - 12:30"
   )
);
```

**This is a picture of what I want:**

[image]]

**This is a picture of the full file:**

[image]]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `NSMutableArray *nameDictionary` is pretty confusing. *This array* is a dictionary.

Comment: Your question is garbled. You say "But I want this:" and then show what appears to be a dictionary that contains nested arrays. Then when you show a plist form of "the full file" you show data in yet a different format, where you show  "calendar" containing an array of arrays where the inner array looks like it contains a label in position 0 and a time range in position 1.

Comment: Oh yeah, and as vadian points out, you've got an array called nameDictionary. You have 3 different structures shown, and garbled code.

Comment: Men come on, i just want to explain... You dont even have to look at the "Calendar". It just as information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want to create an `NSMutableDictionary` and add the array into it:

```
NSMutableDictionary *calDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [calDictionary setObject:nameDictionary forKey:@"Calendar"];
```

**Result**:

```
{
    Calendar =     (
        "6:00 - 16:00",
                (
            "12:00 - 12:30"
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it tommorow!